# Binding.scala: Get current value of a Binding

Tags: scala, scala.js, binding.scala

It seems it is not possible to get the current value of a `Binding` like we can do for a `Var`(using method `value`). I looked at the source and this method is declared as being private for `Binding` class, while it is public for `Var` or for `Binding.Constant` classes. Is-there any reason for making it private in the `Binding` case ? Do you know there is another way to achieve that for a `Binding` ?

Just to give a word about the context, my use-case is the following: I have a complex object within a `Var` and from this Var, I derive several `Binding` representing lists of simple objects. Then I use these `Binding` to render HTML tables within @dom methods. Now I would like to perform some sequential search in the data displayed in the table (without having to derive them again from the original `Var` object)
So, basically, I would like to get the current value of the `Binding` used to show my table in order to perform the search.

Currently, the only option I can think of is to use `Var` instead of `Binding` for my derived objects and then to use a watched binding expression to update the derived `Var` when the source `Var` changes. But this makes the code much less concise and I have the feeling that this would add some performance overhead. Do you have some ideas to accomplish that in a better way?

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Answer (score 0):

You may need `findMapM` (where `M` is `Binding`, `F` is `List` or `Vector`) or other sequential functions in Scalaz. See [Scaladoc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.scalaz/scalaz_2.12/7.2.26/scalaz/Foldable.html#findMapM[M[_],A,B](fa:F[A])(f:A=%3EM[Option[B]])(implicitevidence$3:scalaz.Monad[M]):M[Option[B]]).